Is this logarithmic Dirac comb a tempered distribution?
EDIT (update to use convergence  against a  p-series)
Consider the distribution:
$$T(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \delta(x - \log n)$$
where the coefficients satisfy $|a_n| \leq C n^{-1/2}$ for some constant $C > 0$.
I want to prove that $T(x)$ is a tempered distribution. Here is my approach using comparison with p-series (I am unsure if the bounds are handled prooperly):
For any Schwartz function $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, the action of $T$ is:
$$T[\phi] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \phi(\log n)$$
Using the bound on the coefficients:
$$|T[\phi]| \leq C \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1/2} |\phi(\log n)|$$
For Schwartz functions, we have the standard polynomial decay bound: for any $k \geq 0$, there exists a constant $C_k$ such that:
$$|\phi(x)| \leq C_k(1 + |x|)^{-k}$$
At $x = \log n$, this gives:
$$|\phi(\log n)| \leq C_k(1 + |\log n|)^{-k}$$
Therefore:
$$|T[\phi]| \leq C C_k \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1/2}(1 + |\log n|)^k}$$
For large $n$, we can bound $(1 + |\log n|)^{-k} \leq (\log n)^{-k}$. Using that $\log n < n^\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ and large enough $n$, we get:
$$\frac{1}{n^{1/2}(1 + |\log n|)^k} \leq \frac{1}{n^{1/2}(\log n)^k} \leq \frac{1}{n^{1/2 + \epsilon k}}$$
Taking $\epsilon = 1/4$ and $k = 4$, the series terms are bounded by $\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-3/2}$ converges, our original series must also converge.
Questions:

Is this comparison approach valid? Particularly, is the use of $\log n < n^\epsilon$ rigorous enough?

Are the choices $\epsilon = 1/4$ and $k = 4$ significant, or would other values work?

Does convergence alone prove temperedness, or do we need additional continuity arguments?

How can we relate this bound to the Schwartz space seminorms?



I like this question, but the integral $\int_1^\infty x^{-1/2} (1 + \log x)^{-k} dx$ is divergent. It does not matter how large the power of the logarithmic factor is, it still decays slower that $x^{-1/2}$.

Comment after the edit: The logarithm $\log{n}$ grows slower than $n^{\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon>0$. You can not take $\epsilon=1/4$.

No. If all we know is that $|a_n|\leq n^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, then $T$ is not a tempered distribution:
Take $\phi(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{x^2+1}}$. Since $\sqrt{x^2+1}\leq x+1$, for all $x>0$, we have
$$\phi(\log{n})=e^{-\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(\log{n})^2+1}}\geq e^{-\frac{1}{4}} e^{-\frac{1}{4}(\log{n})}\geq e^{-\frac{1}{4}} n^{-\frac{1}{4}}.$$
So the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}n^{-\frac{1}{2}} \phi(\log{n})$ diverges.
